# Java Spring Application deploy

Tags: angular, spring, deployment

I have created angular - spring boot application and now want to deploy. As far as I understand now I need to by domain and what to do next? I mean should I keep angular in domain host computer and spring application in amazon servers?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is an aws instance,
I think there should be a Jenkins build, code-deploy deployment.